# how to convert string datetime to timestamp in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, timestamp

I have data in a column of **string** type value.

For example : string value : `20201123043000`
i need to get timestamp value : `2020-11-23 04:30:00`

How can i write sql query to get above **timestamp**.
Thanks

Comment: Storing dates as strings is a major design bug. You should be looking for ways to replace that string field with a proper date field. If this is a new application, simply fixing the bad type would be enough and no conversion would be needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TO_TIMESTAMP` [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#id-1.5.8.14.4.2.2.6.1.1.1)

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('20201123043000','YYYYMMDDHHMISS');
```